# Upgrade Angular2-rc1 to Angular2-rc2, facing TypeScript ',' expected. (TS1005)

Tags: javascript, angular, systemjs

I am facing the below exception when I upgrade Angular2 from RC1 to RC2.
[image]

Below is my main.ts, actually I not touch it during the upgrade. The line 13 is where bootstrap method called.

```
import {provide, enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/router-deprecated';
//import {LocationStrategy, Location, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/router-deprecated';

import {LocationStrategy, Location, HashLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
//
//debugger;
////enableProdMode();
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy}]);
```

Could you please help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you get any error's after `npm i --save` ?

Comment: hi, @JS_astronauts, I am not using the node.js because of company policy. So I think it compiled at run time.

Comment: You are missing a closing `)` in your code.  `[ROUTER_PROVIDERS, provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy}]);`, the end should be `})])`, you have `}])`.

Comment: hi, @Claies, thanks for your reply. It works after I added it.

Comment: It is resolved via user comments, though there is no user answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Claies said, I missed one closing ")" in the code.